# Using While True to validate input

Tags: python, while-loop

I am using a While True loop to validate some input, when the input is not in a specified list , i should get an error, the issue i have in the code below that is when i enter either 0 or 1 as input, the action takes place however, i still get the error for an invalid input..

Please just run the main() function then press 1 or 0 as your input and you will see..
I would like the error message not to be shown , thank you :)

```
def main():


      print('\nDear user, welcome to the Online library of Husam.\nPlease choose from the option menu below: ')
      
      print(""" ======LIBRARY MENU=======
   0. To create a book and add it to the book list.
   1. To create a user and add it to the user list.
   2. To Display the current books in the library.
   3. To Display the current users in the library.
   4. Search for a book using: title, author, publisher, or publication date.
   5. Remove a book using: title.
   6. Display total number of books in the library.
   7. Remove a user from the system using: firstname.
   8. Display the number of the users in the system.
   9. Display a user's details using: username.
   10. Borrow a book.
   11 Return a book.
   12. Display number of books a user is borrowing.
   13. Display overdue books that need to be returned.
   14. Exit the system.
                  
                  """)
      choice=input("How may we serve you today? Please choose a number between 0 and 14: \n")
      while True:
              if choice  not in ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14']:
                 print('Error: Invalid input! Please type in only a number between 0 and 14: ')
                 choice = input('\nHow may we serve you today? Please choose a number between 0 and 14: \n')
                 
              else:
                  choice = int(choice)


                  if choice == 0:
                        print(0)
                        
                  elif choice == 1:
                        print(1)

                  elif choice == 2:
                        print('The Library currently has the following books in it: \n')
                        print(2)

                  elif choice == 3:
                        print('The Library currently has the following users in it: \n')
                        print(3)
                  
                  elif choice == 4:
                        print(4)
                        
                  elif choice == 5:
                        print(5)
                        
                  elif choice == 6:
                        print(6)

                  elif choice == 7:
                        print(7)
                        
                  elif choice == 8:
                        print(8)
 
                  elif choice == 9:
                        print(9)
                        
                  elif choice == 10:
                        print(10)

                  elif choice == 11:
                        print(11)

                  elif choice == 12:
                        print(12)

                  elif choice == 13:
                        print(13)

                        
                  elif choice == 14:
                        print(14)
      



                   
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) loop will continue to be evaluated until you [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) out of it. So if you input 1 then:

- `choice` is the string `'1'`
- you convert it to an `int` so `choice` becomes `1`
- the loop repeats and now `choice` is `1` which is not in your list of strings so the error is thrown.

There are a few things you could do to fix it. You could `break` out of your loop when you detect a valid input, or you could not convert `choice` to an int and just compare it as a string.

Comment: i removed the int conversion, and made it a string comparison  , but now i keep getting stuck in an infinite loop ..

Comment: Re-read the first sentence!